# Import date of a certificate into keychain?

Tags: macos

I have a certificate in my keychain, and i need to see when did i introduce it. 
I can't seem to find a way to so. The properties of the certificates don't include that. Is there a log of keychain events somewhere that could help or anything?

Thanks

Comment: What time period might the certificate have been imported – days ago, months ago? Do you have Time Machine back-ups for this time period?

Comment: no higher precision?
No i don't have Time Machine ON, it's OFF

Comment: I wondered if searching through Time Machine keychains would be possible. It is not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

### Keychain Dump

There is no automatic history of the Keychain kept on Mac OS X. You can see everything stored within a keychain file using the following command:

```
security dump-keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

### authd.log

A rotating log of authentication related actions is kept. This may have logged the granting of [rights](http://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/authorization-rights/) needed to import the certificate. It is unlikely but the only place Mac OS X, by default, logs authorization and authentication related activity.

You can see the log using **Console.app** within the `/var/log/authd.log` range of files.

Comment: So without regular back-ups, it appears there is no way to determine when the certificate was imported.

Comment: so far, that what it seems